# What is the advantage of configuring Resource Locations using ResourceHandlerRegistry in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I see in many examples, it is advised to configure(as below) Resource Locations in Spring. In documentation it is mentioned, "cache headers optimized for efficient loading in a web browser". Is this the only advantage? or does Spring security skips authentication on these urls by default?

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resource/**").addResourceLocations(
                "/resource/");
    }
```